# Laravel relationship `whereNotIn` other table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to return all Posts(Model:Post) which have no row in the PostsHistory Model.

My code is:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function remaining_posts(){
    $history = PostHistory::all()->pluck('id');
    return $this->posts->whereNotIn('post_id', $history);
}
```

But I get an error

```
[BadMethodCallException]      
  Method whereNotIn does not exist.
```

Is there any way I could get the remaining_posts through a relationship or can only be done in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your last line to:

```
return $this->posts()->whereNotIn('post_id', $history)->get();
```

i.e.

1. You need to change `posts` to `posts()`. `posts` is a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object which does not have `whereNotIn()` method where as `posts()` will return a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` object which has `whereNotIn()` method defined.
2. `whereNotIn()` returns a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object. So you need to call `get()` to get a collection. But if you want the flexibilty to chain other `Builder` methods to your `remaining_posts()` method, do not use `get()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)